# Not correct Apex Chart render

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

[image: Chart data start not from 0 and ends in out of chart. More over, when I hover at the begin, I see today date. It seem like cycling, that data from 9-th of March doesn't fi]
Chart data start not from 0 and ends in out of chart. More over, when I hover at the begin, I see today date. It seem like cycling, that data from 9-th of March doesn't fit in x-axis